# How to forward headers when using Zuul, Hystrix (and Feign) with Spring Cloud HATEOAS?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, hystrix, spring-hateoas, spring-cloud-feign

### Context

My micro-services application is based on `spring-cloud`: a `zuul` gateway is configured in front of two micro-services: **service-a** and **service-b**.

One of my API requires that **service-a** requests **service-b**; I use `feign` for that.

Zuul send `X-FORWARDED-*` headers to the services, for them to rewrite the HATEOAS links correctly (when the services are configured with `ForwardedHeaderFilter`).

My problem is that the services communicate with each other using `Feign`, which relies on `Hystrix`.
`Hystrix` creates a new thread for each request (we don't use the SEMAPHORE config), so the request in Spring's `RequestContextHolder` is lost in the Feign request from **service-a** to **service-b**, I can't enrich the `feign` request with an `feign` interceptor anymore since the original request is lost.

### Some potential solutions

Forwarding authorization token is now supported directly by Spring with the parameter `hystrix.shareSecurityContext: true`

There isn't any "out of the box" configuration to have Hystrix shares the request between threads.

A solution could be to [implement my own `HystrixConcurrencyStrategy`](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/92), which is a class from netflix.hystrix.
My latest find is this [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/2509/commits/2f2b2037e29150a8b349a3be7c4d528bd14da0c0) that has been sent to spring-cloud-netflix, but unfortunately not integrated.

I can try to copy the code of the Pull request, and create a bean, just as what "eacdy" wrote:

```java
@Bean
public RequestAttributeHystrixConcurrencyStrategy hystrixRequestAutoConfiguration() {
    return new RequestAttributeHystrixConcurrencyStrategy();
}
```

Is there an easier solution to forward the headers from `Zuul` with `Hystrix`?

I suppose that what I am trying to do is very standard when using `Zuul`, `Hystrix`, and `HATEOAS` micro-services that communicate with each other, so maybe there is something that exists already (and that I couldn't find)?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it was quite a common thing to achieve, but after a lot of research, I couldn't find a way to forward the `X-FORWARDED-*` headers automatically with `Feign` and `Hystrix`.

So, I looked for another solution, which works and is quite clean:

- In the `Feign` client from *service-a* to *service-b*, I declared a specific configuration "ServiceBFeignConfig", which, in addition to forward the token, also add the `X-Forwarded-*` headers corresponding to the gateway:

```js
@Configuration
public class ServiceBFeignConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestTokenBearerInterceptor() {
        return new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
                OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details =
                        (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
                requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "bearer " + details.getTokenValue());

                if (applicationProperties.getFeign().getGatewayEnabled()) {
                    requestTemplate.header("X-Forwarded-Host", applicationProperties.getFeign().getGatewayHost());
                    requestTemplate.header("X-Forwarded-Port", applicationProperties.getFeign().getGatewayPort());
                    requestTemplate.header("X-Forwarded-Proto", applicationProperties.getFeign().getGatewayProtocol());
                    requestTemplate.header("X-Forwarded-Prefix", applicationProperties.getFeign().getServiceBPrefix());
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

You can see that the gateway host and port is configured in the properties files (that is served by `Spring Cloud Config` in my case). The *service-b* prefix is also set in these files.

These headers are only added if the "gatewayEnabled" property is set in the properties files.

- You have to ignore this configuration from the component scan of Spring Boot, even if it needs the `@Configuration` annotation, so put it in a "ignorescan" package, and on your main Spring boot class, use:

```js
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myservice" }, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.myservice.ignorescan.*"))
```

At the end, the Forward headers will be added if you have the gatewayEnabled set to true, and the API call to the gateway get the correct HATEOAS links.